# Check iframe status after AJAX File Upload with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, iframe

There is a similar post [Retrieving HTTP status code from loaded iframe with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240/retrieving-http-status-code-from-loaded-iframe-with-javascript) but the solution requires the server-side to return javascript calling a function within the iframe. Instead, I would simply like to check the HTTP status code of the iframe without having to call a function within the iframe itself since my app either returns the full site through HTML or the single object as JSON. Essentially I've been trying to implement a callback method which returns success|failure dependent upon the HTTP status code.

Currently I have `uploadFrame.onLoad = function() { ... so far pretty empty ... }` and I am unsure what to check for when looking for HTTP status codes. Up until now, I've mainly relied upon jQuery's `$.ajax()` to handle success|failure but would like to further understand the mechanics behind XHR calls and iframe use. Thanks ahead of time.

---

**UPDATE**

The solution I came up with using jQuery

```
form.submit(function() {
  uploadFrame.load(function() {
    //using eval because the return data is JSON
    eval( '(' + uploadFrame[0].contentDocument.body.children[0].innerHTML + ')' );
    //code goes here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is injecting `<script>` tag into your iframe `<head>` and insert your "detecting" javascript code there.

something like this:

```
$('#iframeHolderDivId').html($.get('myPage.php'));
$('#iframeHolderDivId iframe head').delay(1000).append($('<script/>').text('your js function to detect load status'));
```

Maybe it's not the best solution but I think it works