# Download file using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an application that runs to print documents. there is a tree view and grid control in the page. The treeview is enabled with the check box. there is another checkbox in the grid. based on the selection i create pdf using itextsharp and want print , download email etc.
i did it but when it down loads , I need the controls to be cleared. this is not happening even i wrote the code to clear. i think the issue may be with the usage of memory stream. So what i am doing is create pdf and saved to a location. So how can I do it with javascript (the download function). My ultimate aim is to clear the controls.

Regards,

Sivajith S.

Comment: for that you have to do something first...

Comment: <a href='docs/DCS.doc'>Download</a> ..can i use this in code behind

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087771/asp-net-downloading-file-through-client-javascript-added-in-eventhandler

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15953840/start-file-download-by-client-from-javascript-call-in-c-asp-net-page

regards...:)

Comment: today, unless you are using HTML5 with web sockets (conditions apply), you cannot do a pure asynchronous upload/download via javascript. You have to create postbacks for it to happen. There are so many techniques which would kind of give you the illusion that its asynchronous like @dholakiyaankit has linked to...

Comment: Completely agree @deostroll